# Как передать параметры нескольких картинок?

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать галерею с выбором памятников и оград к нему. Реализовал сл. образом: 2 картинки памятника, 2 картинки оград.По нажатию открывается в другом блоке и налладываются друг на друга позиционированием. Вопрос: картинка с оградой состоит из 2(задний и передний фон, а я передаю целиком).Как  передать 2 параметра для картинки. Если ли более рациональный способ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
           //1 картинка
 var largeImg = document.getElementById('largeImg');
  document.getElementById('thumbs').onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
      while (target != this) { 
          if (target.nodeName == 'A') {
          showThumbnail(target.href, target.title);
          return false; 
          }
              target = target.parentNode; 
          }
  }
  function showThumbnail(href, title) { 
      largeImg.src = href;
      largeImg.alt = title;
  }
//2 картинка
var largeImg2 = document.getElementById('largeImg2');
document.getElementById('thumbs2').onclick = function(event) {
var target = event.target;
    while (target != this) { 
        if (target.nodeName == 'A') {
        showThumbnail2(target.href, target.title);
        return false; 
        }
            target = target.parentNode; 
        }
}
function showThumbnail2(href, title) { 
    largeImg2.src = href;
    largeImg2.alt = title;
}
```

```html
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="block block-pam" id="thumbs">
                            <a href="img/pam1.png"><img src="img/pam1.png" alt="pam1"></a>
                            <a href="img/pam2.png"><img src="img/pam2.png" alt="pam2"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="block block-ogr" id="thumbs2">
                                <a href="img/ogr1.png"><img src="img/ogr1.png" alt="ogr1"></a>
                                <a href="img/ogr2.png"><img src="img/ogr2.png" alt="ogr2"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-block">
                    <div class="col-6">
                            <img src="img/pam1.png" alt="photo2"  id="largeImg2"> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-6 ">
                            <img src="img/pam1.png" alt="photo1"  id="largeImg"> 
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал данным cпособом: отлавливаю событие и ссылку, отрезаю расширение ".png" и дописываю индекс.

```
var str = target.href;
strz = str.substr(0,str.length-4)+"-z"+ str.substr(str.length-4);
strp = str.substr(0,str.length-4)+"-p"+ str.substr(str.length-4);
```

Передаю в функцию

```
showThumbnail2(strz, strp); {
    largeImg2.src = strz;
    largeImg3.src = strp; 
}
```

Слои позиционировал